# How to remove key data from all rows from json array using javascript

Tags: javascript, arrays, json

This is a JSON array. I want to remove the productID from all the rows.
when I console log I don't want to see the productID in it.

```
"items": 
            [
                { 
                    "productID": "11234567",
                    "added": "TIMESTAMP",
                    "title": "Project",
                    "type": "Weekend Project",
                    "imageURL": "1"
                },

                { 
                    "productID": "11223456",
                    "added": "TIMESTAMP",
                    "title": "Bathroom",
                    "type": "Weekend Project",
                    "imageURL": "2"
                },

                { 
                    "productID": "11223345",
                    "added": "TIMESTAMP",
                    "title": "Curves",
                    "type": "Collections",
                    "imageURL": "3"
                }
            ]
```

The issue was I faced :

I needed to export the array in excel format. I got a simple function for it. but I have to remove some contents from the original JSON which is coming from the backend.

i checked lots of threads in StackOverflow but i cant find the correct solution.

Comment: reassign items to `items.map({productID,...rest} => ({rest}))`

Comment: Please ensure your question meets the stackoverflow question guideline. Show what you've tried and what didn't work where possible.

Comment: If the OP is a beginner @cmgchess how do you expect them to understand that?

Comment: @Andy would have explained if it was an answer. felt a little lazy

Comment: You will inevitably need to loop over the records so however you do that will solve this problem of yours. Simple answer for simple question.

Comment: @cmgchess I think you missing brackets: items.map(({productID,...rest}) => ({rest}))

Comment: @zywy you are correct. my bad

Answer (score 1, accepted):

assuming

```
const items =
            [
                { 
                    "productID": "11234567",
                    "added": "TIMESTAMP",
                    "title": "Project",
                    "type": "Weekend Project",
                    "imageURL": "1"
                },

                { 
                    "productID": "11223456",
                    "added": "TIMESTAMP",
                    "title": "Bathroom",
                    "type": "Weekend Project",
                    "imageURL": "2"
                },

                { 
                    "productID": "11223345",
                    "added": "TIMESTAMP",
                    "title": "Curves",
                    "type": "Collections",
                    "imageURL": "3"
                }
            ]
```

You can just iterate through all elements and delete id property:

```
items.forEach(o=>delete o.productID)
```

or map it into desired structure

```
const newItems = items.map((o)=>({"title":o.title,"added":o.added}))
```

Edit:

In first approach you don't need to create new variable, you edit orginal one, in other one you get new object so you have to assign it to new variable.

Answer (score 2):

You could use [spread syntax](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Spread_syntax)

```js
const data = [{
    "productID": "11234567",
    "added": "TIMESTAMP",
    "title": "Project",
    "type": "Weekend Project",
    "imageURL": "1"
  },

  {
    "productID": "11223456",
    "added": "TIMESTAMP",
    "title": "Bathroom",
    "type": "Weekend Project",
    "imageURL": "2"
  },

  {
    "productID": "11223345",
    "added": "TIMESTAMP",
    "title": "Curves",
    "type": "Collections",
    "imageURL": "3"
  }
]

const result = data.map(p => {
  const { productID, ...rest } = p;
  return { ...rest };
});

console.log(result);
```